# Imported Blender .fbx model appears transparent

Tags: unity, fbx, importing, 3d-modeling

I exported a model that i made in blender to a .fbx file. I imported it to Unity and, as you can see in the image, one arm of my character appears transparent.

[image]

[image]

I already have the normals pointing in the right direction, so i can't see what's causing this. I even tried to create a new arm from the other one, but the problem persisted.

What is causing this?

Comment: I would highly recommend dropping the triangle count on that arm.

Comment: Bump, got the same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know without more details like shader parameters. Could be a problem with alpha channel of either the texture or vertex color's alpha.